# SingleSPA + module federation - Any threshold for memory on loading modules within host application

Tags: lazy-loading, webpack-module-federation, single-spa

I am implementing singlespa + module federation combination for host and remote module.
I have more than 100 modules to be loaded lazily based on route.

I need to know - is there any limitation/threshold if we keep on loading modules in memory via singlespa host application

Why i asked this is because - when i route to my previous module - none of the JS file gets loaded - that means single spa is caching all those modules and reloads from memory

**Host level routing**

```
      {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "angular-header",
            "type": "FEDERATED_MODULE",
            "path": "https://example.com/single-spa-v2/header/remoteEntry.js",
            "remoteEntry": "AngularHeaderApp",
            "remoteModule": "AngularHeader",
            "activeWhen": "/header",
        }
```

**Remote module**

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['@angular/core'],
        },
        "@angular/forms": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['@angular/forms'],
        },
        "@angular/router": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['@angular/router'],
        },
        "@angular/common": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['@angular/common'],
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['@angular/platform-browser'],
        },
        "single-spa-angular": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['single-spa-angular'],
        },
        "rxjs": {
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['rxjs']
        }
      },
      name: "AngularHeaderApp",
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'AngularHeaderApp' },
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "AngularHeader": "./src/main.single-spa.ts",
      },
    })
```

If i revisit my /header route -> nothing is loaded in browser network tab.

Tried coupld of options - but didn't help

- was loading remoteEntry lazily as script tag - so deleted it, but no luck
- tried to delete reference of module by deleting name assigned to remote module - but no luck